# Raster projected in Google Earth Engine showing weird values within R

Tags: raster, r, google-earth-engine

I classified a raster in GEE and I am trying to work with the same within R. I have 7 land cover classes and when I view the output in R, I get something that does not make sense. Please see the values:

```
> lc2018
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 19261, 18167, 349914587  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent     : 633830, 815500, 1090410, 1283020  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : E:/Land Cover Data/Reprojected Image_WG.tif 
names      : Reprojected_Image_WG 
values     : -2147483648, 2147483647  (min, max)
```

How do I ensure that the values tab goes from 1 to 7? When I plot the raster, it looks fine to me.

Comment: Have you tried truncating the data range? Something like: lc2018[lc2018 < | lc2018 > 7] <- NA

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Currently trying it and has been running for the last 10 mins. Will see if it finishes.

Comment: Looks like that worked. I am curious to know if you have used landscapemetrics::sample_lsm()? I am currently trying this: 
                                                                                      
  sample_lsm(lc2018, y = pointsLsm, shape = "circle", size = 1000,
                    level="class"); But I get this error: Error in .local(obj, ...) : NA values in coordinates; Have you encountered this error before? I can start a separate question or modify the one above to reflect this question. Please let me know.

Comment: No, I have not used this function but, try y=coordinates(pointsLsm)  If you still are getting an error look at the coordinates slot in pointsLsm to see if there are, in fact, null coordinate pairs.

Comment: Hi.  Do you know why the values are of such a range? Does the documentation have relevant info?; thedata could be appropriate and these values have meaning.

Comment: @0mn1 I believe that it represents the max and min values that could be stored? I am guessing that's how Google Earth Engine shows it.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Thank you! There were NaN values for the coordinate pairs. Fixed it now.